# Getting active MSConversation to send a message to

Tags: ios, msmessage

I am building a standalone iMessage application. I have a `UIViewController` which inherits from `MSMessagesAppViewController`. It seems `activeConversation` is always nil. Any ideas why? I am mirroring how Apple sends a message in their sample Ice Cream project.

```
 MSConversation *conversation = [self activeConversation];
    if (conversation) {
        MSMessageTemplateLayout *layout = [[MSMessageTemplateLayout alloc] init];
        layout.caption = @"Caption";
        layout.subcaption = @"subcaption";

        MSMessage *message = [[MSMessage alloc] init];
        message.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.example.com"];
        message.layout = layout;

        [conversation insertMessage:message completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error sending message %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"No &%#%&^# conversation found");
    }
```

It may be worth noting the `UIViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: MSConversation *conversation = [MSConversation new]; will send a new message, still struggling to get current thread however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can only have one instance of `MSMessagesAppViewController` which will actually interact with the conversation threads. Other controllers can inherit from `MSMessagesAppViewController` but none of the conversation protocol or compact/expanded transition delegate methods will fire in those instances, just the first instance the extension encounters.